# How to stop my game object from sliding in Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to create 2D movement in unity that is fast and responsive. I wanted the movement to move responsively to the player movement and especially stop the second the user lets go of the key. The issue I'm facing is that when the key is released, it still slides for a slight amount of time afterwards when the game object should just halt immediately.

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class rotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed;
    private float move_hor;
    private float move_ver;

    void Update()
    {
        move_hor = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        move_ver = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed * move_hor, speed * move_ver);
    }
}
```

I tried to implement

```
rb.Sleep()
```

or

```
Vector2.zero
```

however, it doesn't stop the gameobject immediately. I'm new to C# so maybe I haven't been implementing them correctly. If so, please show the correct way to implement them.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the line where you assign the velocity to the `FixedUpdate()` method. `FixedUpdate()` is similar to the `Update()` method but it is called fixed amount of times in a given interval whereas `Update()` is called for every new frame.

Physics calculations are mostly done in `FixedUpdate()`. For more information I suggest you research the differences between `Update()` and `FixedUpdate()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you assign velocity to your rigidbody, it's like pushing the object. The velocity is only decreased by the physic of your game : friction with another object or with the air.
If you want to translate your object and, when the key is released, immediatly stop it, use `transform.Translate` instead : [the doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html)